# How to include extra moment locales in Meteor

Tags: meteor, momentjs

I'm wondering how to include extra moment locales in Meteor, is there a canonical way or do I have to hack the framework to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the `moment` doc](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/) you can just define a new locale:

```
moment.locale('mylocale', {/* ... */});
```

The best way to integrate this into your application is through a package.
To do so, `meteor --create yourpackage` + `meteor add yourpackage`, in your `package.js` file write [`api.use('momentjs:moment')`](https://atmospherejs.com/momentjs/moment) to have access to it, then define your new locale in the `yourpackage.js` generated file.
You can also do [every kind of package sorcery](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/packagejs) that's possible with Meteor.

Answer (score 2):

That should be easily done using moment customization feature: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/